# Set Execution Policy Powershell in Azure web application

Tags: powershell, azure, asp.net-web-api

I need to execute some powershell code from a web api which I have deployed in an Azure App Service. I couldn't achieve to se 'Set-ExecutionPolicy' because I need to set it to unrestricted but I get an error

> File D:\home\powershell\teams_v2.psm1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170

.

I have the following code

```
using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
                            {
                                runspace.Open();
                                var script = String.Format(@"Import-Module 'D:\home\powershell\teams_v2.psm1'
                                                            connect-teamsservice -user admin@contoso.onmicrosoft.com -tenant contoso.onmicrosoft.com
                                                            new-Team -displayname '{0}' -description '{1}' -smtpaddress '{2}' -alias '{3}' -type 'private'",
                                                        group.Name, group.Description, String.Format("{0}@contoso.onmicrosoft.com", group.MailNickName), "team");
                                RunspaceInvoke scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke();
                                // set powershell execution policy to unrestricted
                                //scriptInvoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted");
                                Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
                                pipeline.Commands.AddScript(script);

                                // add an extra command to transform the script
                                // output objects into nicely formatted strings

                                // remove this line to get the actual objects
                                // that the script returns. For example, the script

                                // "Get-Process" returns a collection
                                // of System.Diagnostics.Process instances.

                                pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");

                                // execute the script

                                Collection <PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();

                                // close the runspace

                                runspace.Close();

                                // convert the script result into a single string

                                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                                foreach (PSObject obj in results)
                                {
                                    stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
                                }

                            }
```

How can I achieve this to correctly load the ps module and use its functions.

Comment: You'll need to find a different way to do it. PowerShell's execution policy gets set in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, which is restricted in the App Service sandbox: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#writing-to-registry